# How do I install a self compiled android image onto an SD card, and run Android from said sd card?

Tags: rom-flashing, external-sd, installation, android-sdk

I have compiled a generic version of Android KitKat from source, and run it in the Android SDK emulator.  I now want to take that version of Android I created, which sits in my `../out/target/product/generic/` folder and install it to run on an SD card in a tablet.

How would I go about partitioning, formatting, copying over all the required Android files, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I'm afraid your issue is beyond the scope of our site (it's rather a development specific question). Furthermore: As you write "generic version", I'm not sure whether it would even run on your device, unless you've included the hardware specific drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome Francisco :)  I currently have a Linux dev environment set up.  I did indeed have a rough time getting adb to recognize the android device through Windows.  The manufacturer does not provide USB drivers.  It resulted in me switching to Linux as it doesn't require OEM drivers to detect the device.

I have been searching all over the past week or so trying to find some help with unlocking the bootloader on this device, but can't find anything.  It seems most sites focus on the most popular and widely used devices.  And that makes sense.

Comment: So I've given up on rooting and flashing my device.  I was going to try and setup a dual boot through SD Card.

Comment: As for hardware drivers required by android, it may not run with all the features or not run at all, but I would like to at least try.  I could always recompile with changes or added drivers.  Recompiling the kernel and dealing with patches is also a concern.  Right now I'm just trying to get something running.

Comment: Also Sorry Izzy, I meant to thank you for the welcome.  I think I saw an edit to my original post done by Francisco, and thought he was the commenter a second.  Thank you Izzy.

Comment: No problem. You're right, Francisco did an edit to your post. He would have welcomed you as well, but I was faster. So we take your thanks together and share :) Good luck with your issue, and sorry I cannot further help with it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can you adb to push it on, but don't take my word. You run the risk of bricking your device. XDA-developers.com is the best place to ask Android questions. They also deal with this technical side.

Sorry for this not being a real answer, but I can't comment and they can help you out more.

Generic Answer

1. Get root access
2. Unlock Bootloader
3. Install custom recovery like a Clockwork Mod
4. Flash ROM

Comment: I have frequented that site many times this past week.  Sadly, it seems almost all questions on that site referring to my device or a model similar get no or vague responses.  I guess it is to be expected since this isn't a Samsung/Nexus/etc.

Comment: First step is to root your device. Next is to unlock your Bootloader. Once you get those two steps done then the rest is a breeze. Use your custom recovery to install your ROM.

Comment: There is no need to partition. Recoveries allow you to boot in select ROMS. I don't remember if they install on the phone or sd card, but my bet is on the phone. Ivan imagine some problems with booting from the sdcard with a phone. What phone is it?

Comment: The closest cousin would be the Positivo YPY 10.

Comment: I have never heard of it. However, I just looked it up. They look nice, but I can't understand the web page. Google is your best friend. Go through as many Google pages as you can until you find a root and unlocked Bootloader solution.    If you had sufficient knowledge in reverse engineering then you might be able to create a root kit to give you root. I would Google and check XDA. XDA does seem more knowledgable for Android technical. Maybe even spam thread n XDA until you get a reply?